# PHP function descriptions not loaded. Try M-x php-extras-generate-eldoc

Tags: spacemacs, php-mode

I keep getting this annoying error that pops up in a dialog every few seconds.

I've tried running `php-extras-generate-eldoc` but that seems to point to http://doc.php.net/ which does not seem to be responding, and hence seems to be stuck at `Contacting host...`.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76819

Is there a way I can disable this particular feature?

I've tried to remove all references to php-extras in my .spacemacs file, but no change in behavior.

Comment: Chris, Tried your suggestion and still get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the following in my spacemacs config:

```
   dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '(
                                    php-extras
                                    )
```